# Array of <? extends T> in Java

Tags: java, arrays, generics, extends

Is it possible to declare an array of something that extends some class?

I can do:

```
Map[] foo;
T[] foo;     //(in generic class)
Map... foo;  //(as argument declaration for "implicit" array)
T... foo;    //(as argument declaration in generic class for "implicit" array)
```

But I need something like:

```
<? extends Map>[] foo;
<? extends T>[] foo;     //(in generic class)
<? extends Map>... foo;  //(as argument declaration for "implicit" array)
<? extends T>... foo;    //(as argument declaration in generic class for "implicit" array)
```

It could be used some `List<? extends T>` instead but it's not quite an array. For Example, if you want to use it in a like this:

```
public class MyClass<T> {
   public void foo(int someOtherStuff, <? extends T>... optionalArray){
      //some code
   }
}
```

*Maybe "implicit" array isn't correct, please tell me how they're called correctly.*

Comment: Umm, all references in Java can already hold subtypes, so something like `Number[] foo = {new Integer(0), new Double(1), new Long(2), ...};` is already perfectly valid. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the way.. I found the answer to the initial question, maybe somebody needs it one day:

```
public class MyClass<T> {
   public <R extends T> void foo(int someOtherStuff, R... optionalArray){
      //some code
   }
}
```

Found it by mistake by looking at the implementation of `Arrays.asList(T[] a)`. In knew I've seen that syntax somewhere just didn't remember where.

Comment: Ah, didn't know that one. Where is the exact benefit over just going with a `T...` array?

Comment: In the Example above there is maybe no benefit, but it could be helpful if you have:
`public <R extends T> void foo(List<R[]> list){/**/}`
Then the method will accept Lists of arrays of anything that extends T. But I never needed it... maybe in future now that I know it exists :)

Answer (score 4):

Objects in Java are polymorphic: You can simply declare an array of a common base type and have objects of all kinds of derived classes in it.

To go with Radiodef's example, this is valid code:

```
Number[] foo = {new Integer(0), new Double(1), new Long(2), ...};
```

What Java does not have is a mechanism that defines an array restricted to one particular derived type of some known base class, where the particular derived type is only known at runtime.

So, if you mean `public void foo(int someOtherStuff, <? extends T>... optionalArray)` to check whether the objects in `optionalArray` are all of the same derived type, then the answer is that this can not be done automatically. You can however use

```
public void foo(int someOtherStuff, T... optionalArray)
```

to get the guarantee that all objects in the array are derived of the same class `T`. They may be of different derived types, though.

Comment: Furthermore, even arrays are covariant. `Number[] foo = new Integer[1];` is perfectly valid as well, even if it comes with caveats, namely possible `ArrayStoreException`.

Comment: Sorry Felix, found the exact answer to my initial question and marked that one as accepted ;-)

Answer (score 0):

> You're completely right Radiodef and Felix
>   Thanks a lot for your detailed explaination!

I just thought I have to declare it like that because something didn't work and I thought that was the problem. But something different was really the problem. Just want to mention it quickly:

I have following generic class:

```
public class MyClass<T> {
   public void foo1(List<Object> someList){ //wrong
      //some code
   }
   public void foo1(Object... someArray){
      //some code
   }
   public void foo2(List<? extends T> someList){
      foo1(someList);
      //some code
   }
}
```

I wanted that `foo2` would invoke `foo1(List<Object> someList)` but instead it invoked `foo1(Object... someArray)` even though `T` will always extend Object **(or not?)**

However, to make that work, `foo1(List<Object> someList)` needs to be declared like this:

```
   public void foo1(List<? extends Object> someList){ //correct
      //some code
   }
```

then `foo2` will invoke this rather than `foo1(Object... someArray)`.

Comment: Eh ... this is definitely something to think about :) Java seems to think it easier to treat the list of `? extends T` like an array of base objects as opposed treating it like a list of base objects. Why this is so, I don't know. It's a good question, just ask again!